# Testing for differences in mean in multiplayer game score

Tags: hypothesis-testing

A multiplayer game exists, in which every round two players from the population are selected at random to play a single match of the game, and either gain or lose score based on their performance against one another. The game continues for many rounds (certainly enough that each player gets to take part in several matches).

Half of the population use one strategy, and the other half use a different strategy. I'm interested to know whether there exists a significant difference between the two strategies - in terms of the final score - but I can't figure out which test to use.

I don't think we can say that the data is independent, since a winner in a single match implies a loser, but I can't think of any meaningful way to pair players from the two sub-populations. I also don't think we can assume a normal distribution in the data.

Answer (score 0):

An ordinary [t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) should suffice this. If you have more groups then an [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) would make sense. As far as I understand correctly, it's not about the single players, so it doesn't matter who is a winner or loser as you say, it's ultimately about the final score. So I would test the final score against the strategies.
You could also run a linear model for a more elaborated concept.

I would advice [ggstatsplot](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/), it's quite simple to do.

Comment: Doesn't the t-test require a normal distribution?

Comment: true, I mixed it with the t-distribution for which the lack of non-normality was actually the motivation for..  a bit confusing. I guess Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney makes sense, then.